# Using commands to fire usercontrol method

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I need some help and I hope you can help me. I have a complex usercontrol with a method that changes the color of all elements inside. When I try to connect it with a method stub in the MainWindow-Code-behind, I can fire it up easily. I want to use MVVM in the future so now I want to connect it to a button in the main window through commands.

So here's my ViewModel and my MainWindow.cs

```
public class ViewModel
{ 
    public DelegateCommands TestCommand { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        TestCommand = new DelegateCommands(OnExecute, CanExecute);

    }

    bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    void OnExecute()
    {

        //testUC.NewColor(); HERE I WANT TO START THE UC-METHOD
    }
}




 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ViewModel _ViewModel = null;
    public plate tplate;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _ViewModel = new ViewModel();


    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tplate = new plate();
    }
}
```

On my MainWindow-View I have a simple button and the usercontrol.

```
<exte:plate x:Name="testUC" Grid.Column="1"/>
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="43,247,0,0" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
```

I want to start the UC-Method in the OnExecute()-Method but I'm not able to select the "testUC" because it's not available in this context.

Is there an easy way to start the UC-Methods through command bindings?

Thanks for any help.

Timo

Comment: Since the colors are visual appearance, there is no reason to put this logic into a VM. So you could stick to your approach, if you're able to get it run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not even just the color, it is used for offset- and other methods. I want to start it from a devexpress-ribbonbutton (w/o any click- or similar events), so I need the command way.

Comment: Sounds like you're implementing a `CustomControl`. Usually, you would implement such things in the code behind of the control. Nevertheless, you can use the `ICommand` approach by binding to the control.

Comment: Hey. Thanks again for your answer. I'm sorry to confuse Custom with User-Control... Well, I think, I will use code-behind for the control but nevertheless I'm interested to know how this should work with commands. I tried with the code in the main-question part but if I click on the button, nothing happens (even in the Debugging-Mode).

Answer (score 0):

How to solve you're binding problem. First, most bindings are related to the most specific `DataContext`. Means, you have to set your control as such. E.g.

```cs
public class MySpecialButton : Button
{
    public MySpecialButton()
    {
        DataContext = this; // there are other possibilties, but this is the easiest one
    }
}
```

With this you can bind every command implemented in `MySpecialButton`.

Another possibility is to use bindings with relative source. E.g.

```xml
<Button Command="{Binding TheCmd, RelativeSource={AncestorType={x:Type MySpecialButton}}}" />
```

You could even declare the `DataContext` with the method in the example above.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hey. Thanks again. I will give it a try and let you know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tried it the latter way you described ("Button" is the Button I want to use to trigger the method, "NewPlate" is the method-name and exte:plate is the customcontrol-type):

```
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="43,247,0,0" Command="{Binding NewPlate, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type exte:plate}}}" />
```

But again, nothing happens.

To understand your first suggestion correctly, I have to declare my Custom-Control as a Button instead of a user control? I do not understand, where I have to put the datacontext stuff. I'm just using a standard wpf-button to trigger the custom-control-method. I do not have any class for this button where I can declare a datacontext.